# Multivariate polynomial is never squarefree at integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

Let $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ be squarefree polynomial with integer
coefficients. Assume $f$ at integers is not always divisible
by a fixed square $m^2 > 1$.

Is it possible $f$ to never be squarefree at integers?

I suspect this is impossible.

Comment: Crossposted at MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2438734/multivariate-polynomial-is-never-squarefree-at-integers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a supplement to Ilya Bogdanov's answer.

For univariate polynomials Granville (Int. Math. Res. Not. 1998, 991-1009) deduced from the $abc$-conjecture that there are infinitely many natural numbers $x$ such that $f(x)$ is square-free; in fact these numbers have positive density. The same is known unconditionally when $\deg f\leq 3$, by the work of Hooley (Mathematika 14 (1967), 21-26). In addition, Granville's conditional result was extended to multivariate polynomials by Poonen (Duke Math. J. 118 (2003), 353-373).

Comment: You can find the paper of Granville [here](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/polysq3.pdf).

Comment: So it would be accurate to say that we do not know definitively for degree greater than $3$ but do very strongly suspect that it is indeed impossible.

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz: Yes.

Comment: There is alleged counterexample to Ilya's answer, check the comments.

Answer (score 9):

**The answer has been edited, due to a mistake found by joro and explained by Jose Brox --- thanks to both of them! Now we reduce the $n$-variate case to the $(n-1)$-variate one...**

The claim that an $n$-variate polynomial will always have a square-free value under our assumptions holds if and only if the same claim holds for an $(n-1)$-variate polynomial (and hence for a univariate polynomial, which still seems to be open). The "only if" part is trivial; let us show the "if" part.

We may assume that $f(\mathbf 0)\neq 0$. For any $p^2\mid f(\mathbf 0)$ there exists $\mathbf x_p$ such that $p^2\nmid f(\mathbf x_p)$. Using CRT, we find an $\mathbf x$ such that $p^2\nmid f(\mathbf x)$ for all $p^2\mid f(\mathbf 0)$.
**[EDIT]** Moreover, 
there are $n$ sets of the form $S_i=P\mathbb Z+a_i$ such that every $\mathbf x\in\prod_{i=1}^n S_i$ works.

Consider now the polynomial $g(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_{n-1},t)=f(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},tx_{n-1})$. It is also square-free (when passing from $g$ to $f$ by substituting $t=x_n/x_{n-1}$, a square may disappear only if it was $x_{n-1}^2$; this cannot happen since $g(\mathbf 0)=f(\mathbf 0)\neq0$). Next, there are only finitely many values $\alpha$ such that $g(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},\alpha)$ is not square-free: at these exceptional $\alpha$ the discriminant of $g$ with respect to one of the $x_i$ should vanish, and all these discriminants are not identically zero.

Now we choose $\alpha\in S_nS_{n-1}^{-1}$ for which $f_1(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},\alpha)$ is square-free; let $\alpha=k_n/k_{n-1}$ with $k_i\in S_i$. Then the polynomial (with integer coefficients) $h(x_1,\dots,x_{n-2},x_{n-1})=f(x_1,\dots,x_{n-2},k_{n-1}x_{n-1},k_nx_{n-1})=g(x_1,\dots,k_{n-1}x_{n-1},\alpha)$ is square-free, and for $k_i\in S_i$ the values $h(k_1,\dots,k_{n-2},1)=f(k_1,\dots,k_n)$ and $h(\mathbf 0)=f(\mathbf 0)$ have no common square divisors (other than 1). By the $(n-1)$-variate case, $h$ has a square-free value, therefore so does $f$.

Comment: See also my response.

Comment: Isn't this counterexample: $f(x,y,z)=(x^2+2)^2+y-z$. The bad prime is $2$ and $f(1,1,1)=3^2$. Then $f(t,t,t)=(t^2+2)^2$ which is never squarefree.

Comment: As @joro shows, you need also to assure that $g(t)$ is squarefree as a polynomial.

Comment: @JoseBrox I am not sure yours is enough, g(t) may always be divisible by square even if it and its content are squarefree like $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$

Comment: @joro What Ilya Bogdanov was saying is that the multivariate case can be reduced to the univariate case, since if $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is square-free and without a divisor $m^2>1$ then, he claims, we can find a polynomial in one variable $g(t)$ whose image is inside the image of $f$, so that if we know the result to be true for one variable, then it would be true also for several variables. But his reasoning above has a flaw, as you have shown: from $f$ he has got a polynomial $g(t)$ which satisfies it has no $m^2>1$ when $f$ does, but he has forgotten to guarantee that $g(t)$ is squarefree!

Comment: Thanks to joro and @JoseBrox! I've corrected the answr (=added more than it contained before...); hope it works now...

Comment: Since you care about the discriminant, do you cover never squarefree cases like $4x$ or $x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$?

Comment: All I need from discriminants is that they are non-zero, since I want to avoid squares of _non-constant_ factors (lack of which was my mistake in the previous version). Since the obtained polynomial _has_ values which contain no common squares, I do not care of the constant factors...

Comment: For $f(x,y)=4x+y-1$ which part of your reduction avoids $y=4y'+1$?

Comment: I don't understand the question, sorry. The zero point is kept to be zero.